# Can the President issue an implicit blanket pardon for specific offenses?

Tags: united-states, president, executive, pardon

Yesterday, President Trump made a [speech](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/2017/07/donald-trump-law-enforcement-speech-long-island-ms-13) applauded by law enforcement encouraging their rough treatment of suspects, specifically including a removal of protection from physical injury when a suspect is being loaded into a police vehicle for transportation.  The context of the speech indicated that the rough treatment should be especially applied on the basis of perceived national origin.

If some career prosecutor in the Department of Justice didn't or doesn't "get the memo" against investigation and prosecution of federal civil rights violations by police, could an officer accused of this violation successfully claim that this speech (and/or others like it) contained a presidential pardon?

---

It seems clear that no conviction needs exist at the time of the pardon nor does the specific crime need to be identified (e.g. Ford's blanket pardon of Nixon), nor does the specific individual being pardoned have to be identified (e.g. Carter's pardoning of draft dodgers), and that official pronouncements from this President do not necessarily come in formally structured executive orders (e.g. Tweeted ban on transgender military service).  These factors suggest the answer may be "yes," but I am not familiar with the actual requirements of what it takes to make a pardon valid.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, that cant be a pardon for those police officers who would be now influenced to take more violent actions towards those they detain.
Pardons are only applicable to past actions. You may be pardoned before charges are filed, but the actions must have already occured.

Though I less certain about this, simply because Ive never heard such a thing proposed, I would also note that it is highly improbable that the actual statement he made - generic and during a speech - could everbe interpreted as an affirmative act intending to grant pardons to anyone who may act in that manner in the future.

Comment: The question was careful to focus on **federal** civil rights law.

Comment: Apologies, did not notice that. The middle paragraph is applicable, though.

Comment: Officers who have done these actions already might be interested in claiming the pardon, whether or not they've been prosecuted/convicted yet (those processes take a while!).  The question still stands.

Comment: True, but I am confident no court would interpret that speech as contituting a pardon. Pardons are in fact actual things that must be filed, etc.

Comment: There is an Office of Pardon Attorney that formally handles these matters, except for in the case of military pardons where they are sent to the secretary of the department. Of course, because the power is unlimited, except in impeachment, it is foreseeable that a president could affirmatively state in a speech “I am pardoning you for ____.” But Trump did not do that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I hope you don't mind if I keep the question fully open awaiting an answer with better sources than "the confidence of a ransom person in the Internet." This Administration has repeatedly shown that just because there are traditional formal ways of doing things, does not mean they're going to do them that way, unless there are clear and specific laws requiring them to (and maybe not even then).

Comment: Ha, by all means, your question. Im unable to cite the way Id like at the moment, but Id note that this would come down to a courts interpretation if somebody was pointing to this speech (or one like it) as their reason for believing they were pardoned. I say Im confident that speech (or one like it, which of course does not include a speech where the president affirmatively expresses an intent to pardon such indviduals) would not be construed as a pardon because, by its language, no reasonable person would be led to believe that and, thus, unless D Trump Jr is the judge, a court would reject